# Codeception + Selenium Standalone sees strings not visible in browser

Tags: selenium

When running Codeception and Selenium on Ubuntu 18 this was working fine:

example PhpDriver test:

```
public function loadWidgetPage(AcceptanceTester $I)
{
    $I->amOnPage("/en/system/widget.php?id=22002");
    $I->see("Widget:");
    $I->dontSee("error");
    $I->dontSeeInSource("Fatal error");
}
```

Now I am trying to run the same test with Codeception and Selenium Standalone on Ubuntu 22.

I get

```
Failed asserting that on page /en/system/widget.php?id=22002
-->  Widget - | Acme Widget Settings [redacted]
[Content too long to display. See complete response in '/home/vagrant/widgeter/tests/_output/' directory]
--> does not contain "error".
```

However, the word "error" is being detected in things like hidden fields or even alert text strings:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#inquiry").bind("click", function(e) {
        $.post("/en/system/inquiry.php", postData,
            function(data){
                if(data == "NG"){
                    alert("Error erasing inquiry.  Are you logged in?");
                }
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

Can Selenium Standalone ignore strings invisible to the user?

My Ubuntu version:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release:    22.04
Codename:   jammy
```

Comment: What exact version of Ubuntu are you using?  Show the output of `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Thank you, @ThomasWard .  Ubuntu version added in question.